# How to connecet to SQL database using Singleton Design Pattern java ?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, singleton

Also, who can show the difference from native code? For example, connect to the database with Java and do it with Singleton Design pattern. What are advantages of using it?

Comment: I assume the motivation is to use a single connection across the application. Post you connection code as a start.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection instance should be preserved and you can only retrieve your connection via getConnection() method (getInstance of the Singleton pattern)

Here is a sample code;

## A - Sample Database Utility Based On Singleton Design Pattern of Gang Of Four

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBUtil {

    private final String HOST;
    private final String PORT;
    private final String DB_NAME;
    private final String USER;
    private final String PASSWORD;

    private final String TARGET_TABLE;
    private final String COLUMN_NAME;

    private final String CONNECTION_STRING;

    private final String SELECT_ALL_SQL;
    private final String SELECT_COLUMN_SQL;
    private final String INSERT_SQL;

    private Connection conn;

    public DBUtil() {
        // Database Parameters
        HOST                    = "your_host_here";
        PORT                    = "your_port_number_here";
        DB_NAME                 = "your_database_name";
        USER                    = "your_databse_user_here";
        PASSWORD                = "your_database_password_here";

        // Database Tables
        TARGET_TABLE            = "your_table_name";
        COLUMN_NAME             = "your_tables_column_name";

        CONNECTION_STRING       = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", HOST, PORT, DB_NAME);

        // Query Strings
        SELECT_ALL_SQL          = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s.%s WHERE id=?", DB_NAME, TARGET_TABLE);
        SELECT_COLUMN_SQL       = String.format("SELECT %s FROM %s.%s WHERE id=?", COLUMN_NAME, DB_NAME, TARGET_TABLE);
        INSERT_SQL              = String.format("INSERT INTO %s.%s (id, name) values (?, ?)", DB_NAME, TARGET_TABLE);

        printConfiguration();

        conn = null;
    }

    private void printConfiguration() {
        System.out.println("******************************************************************************");
        System.out.println("DB_NAME                    : " + DB_NAME);
        System.out.println("USERNAME                   : " + USER);
        System.out.println("PASSWORD                   : " + PASSWORD);
        System.out.println("CAMT TABLE                 : " + TARGET_TABLE);
        System.out.println("******************************************************************************");
    }

    private void getConnection() {
        if(conn != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection already established with db");

            return;
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection FAILED");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        if(conn == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            conn.close();

            conn = null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int insert(int id, String column) {
        int rowNum;

        getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        try {
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT_SQL);
            System.out.println("SQL: " + INSERT_SQL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, column);

            rowNum = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println(rowNum + " rows are inserted");

            return rowNum;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Model getModel(int id) {
        getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Model model = new Model();

        try {
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_ALL_SQL);
            System.out.println("SQL: " + SELECT_ALL_SQL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                model.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                model.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return model;
    }

    public String getName(int id) {
        getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        String name = null;

        try {
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(SELECT_COLUMN_SQL);
            System.out.println("SQL: " + SELECT_ALL_SQL);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            if(rs.next()) {
                name = rs.getString("name");
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return name;
    }

}
```

## B - Model Used in Singleton Database Utility Demo

```
public class Model {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Model() {}

    public Model(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```